# why html is not showing after using plugin in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using this plugin and follow all steps but my output is not showing why ?
https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/#/#quick-start
here is my code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvug59?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

```
<ngx-graph
  class="chart-container"
  [view]="[500, 200]"
  [links]="[
    {
      id: 'a',
      source: 'first',
    target: 'second',
      label: 'is parent of'
    }, {
      id: 'b',
      source: 'first',
      target: 'third',
      label: 'custom label'
    }
  ]"
  [nodes]="[
    {
      id: 'first',
      label: 'A'
    }, {
      id: 'second',
      label: 'B'
    }, {
      id: 'third',
      label: 'C'
    }
  ]"
>
</ngx-graph>
```

Comment: Starting with a new ng-app and following the instructions, the example on the ngx-graph site works for me. You did run `npm init` in the project folder and then `npm install @swimlane/ngx-graph`?

Comment: It's weird.. I'm not seeing any issue running in local but I couldn't run on stackblitz.